# Causal Inference where the treatment assignment is randomised

Tags: statistics, ab-testing, causality, abtest, causalml

I have mostly worked with Observational data where the treatment assignment was not randomized. In the past, I have used PSM, IPTW to balance and then calculate ATE.
My problem is:
Now I am working on a problem where the treatment assignment is randomized meaning there won't be a confounding effect. But treatment and control groups have different sizes. There's a bucket imbalance.

Now should I just analyze the data as it is and run statistical significance and Statistical power test?
Or shall I balance the imbalance of sizes between the treatment and control using let's say covariate matching and then run significance tests?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you don't need equal group sizes to estimate treatment effects.
Unequal groups will not bias the estimate, it will just affect its variance - namely, reducing the precision (recall the statistical power is determined by the smallest group, so unequal groups is less sample-efficient, but not categorically wrong).

you can further convince yourself with a simple simulation (code below). Showing that for repeated draws, the estimation is not biased (both distributions perfectly overlay), but having equal groups have improved precision (smaller standard error).

[image: simulation showing equal groups has better precision over repeated trials]

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

n_trials = 100
balanced = {
    True: (100, 100),
    False: (190, 10),
}
effect = 2.0
res = []
for i in range(n_trials):
    np.random.seed(i)
    noise = np.random.normal(size=sum(balanced))
    for is_balanced, ratio in balanced.items():
        t = np.array([0]*ratio[0] + [1]*ratio[1])
        y = effect * t + noise
        m = sm.OLS(y, t).fit()
        res.append((is_balanced, m.params[0], m.bse[0]))

res = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=["is_balanced", "beta", "se"])
g = sns.jointplot(
    x="se", y="beta",
    hue="is_balanced",
    data=res
)
# Annotate the true effect:
g.fig.axes[0].axhline(y=effect, color='grey', linestyle='--')
g.fig.axes[0].text(y=effect, x=res["se"].max(), s="True effect")
```